Selenium Running Indefinitely?
I'm trying to run Selenium in Python to scrape lyrics from Genius.com. For some reason my code runs indefinitely with the browser staying open. Here's the code I'm running:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

timeout = 10
driver = launchBrowser(path)

# Get Body Text
body = EC.presence_of_element_located(
    By.CLASS_NAME, "ReferentFragmentdesktop__Highlight-sc-110r0d9-1"
)
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(body)
paragraphs = driver.find_elements(
    By.CLASS_NAME, "ReferentFragmentdesktop__Highlight-sc-110r0d9-1"
)
driver.quit()

I defined launchBrowser and path earlier in the code and am having no issues with that. I would expect my program to either close once the timeout time has been hit in WebDriverWait or once the code gets to driver.quit(). For some reason neither is happening and my browser window stays open perpetually. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.
I've tried scraping other sites and those seem to work fine, but for some reason this code is stuck in a perpetual loop and I'm not sure why. I'm using Chrome.

some servers may have complex system to detect scrapers and stop them. Some of them keep open connection but they don't send data - and code may wait forever - so it can't get HTML and it can't use WebDriverWait because it still wait for data. maybe use print() before and after launchBrowser(path) to see if this function was finished.

This looks like it could be the cause. I'm able to print before launchBrowser(path) but not after.

what is launchBrowser()? I never see it in Selenium. What browser do you use? I tested page with selenium 4.19 and driver for Firefox and it loads page - but I load it only once. I didn't test how it behaves when I start loading many pages in short time

I'm guessing that launchBrowser(path) is a function that opens the browser for you. I'm also guessing that the
paragraphs = driver.find_elements( By.CLASS_NAME, "ReferentFragmentdesktop__Highlight-sc-110r0d9-1" ) isn't being found.
With from selenium.webdriver import Chrome there is Chrome().implicitly_wait()...

def implicitly_wait(self, time_to_wait: float) -> NoneSets a sticky
timeout to implicitly wait for an element to be found, or a command to
complete. This method only needs to be called one time per session. To
set the timeout for calls to execute_async_script, see
set_script_timeout.

This will wait for a number of seconds and if the element can't to be found or the command can't complete an exception is raised.
This will give you a clear indication that the element isn't being found.
